# 'Printing' dialog box style

Tags: c#

Can I change the 'Printing' dialog box style that appears when the method
PrintDocument.Print is invoked? I need to change title, message, background, OK button...

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are we talking making a Preview dialog or the actual printing dialog which pops up when you click print?

Comment: I'm talking about printing dialog which shows the number of pages prepared for printing. The title of the dialog box is "Printing", message is for example "Page 1 of document".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some useful ideas [here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-318766.html), with examples of custom PrintController and PrintDialog.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not: .NET uses WinAPI calls like `printDlg` to show the dialog and it's not customizable. The dialog itself can differ depending on printers installed and some other factors as far as I know. See [Extending PrintDialog article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/TopMostPrintDlg.aspx) for some details.